# how to persist data with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb

I am building a docker-compose including influxdb and grafana for my team. Here is what I was able to create :

```
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.7.3
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
      - '8088:8088'
    volumes:
      - "/data/docker-volumes/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb"
      - "/etc/ssl/myserver:/etc/ssl/myserver"
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=db0
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=${INFLUXDB_USERNAME}
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${INFLUXDB_PASSWORD}
      - INFLUXD_TLS_CERT=${TLS_CERT}
      - INFLUXD_TLS_KEY=${TLS_KEY}
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - "/data/docker-volumes/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana"
      - "/home/docker-compose/grafana-provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning"
      - "/etc/ssl/myserver:/etc/ssl/myserver"
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${GRAFANA_USERNAME}
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${GRAFANA_PASSWORD}
      - GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE=${TLS_CERT}
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY=${TLS_KEY}
      - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=url
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://url:3000
```

To make the data permanent, I have created an external volume `/data/docker-volumes/influxdb/data`

All this works well during creation **(up)**, startup **(start)** and shutdown **(stop)**. However, as soon as I break the containers **(down)** to simulate a failure and put them back together **(up)**, the data is overwritten and I have to reinitialise influxDB.

Do you have any idea what the error is? My head's in it too much and I can't see what I'm doing "wrong"

Thanks for your help

Thierry

Comment: The [Docker Hub `influxdb` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/influxdb) notes that you should mount the volume on `/var/lib/influxdb2` – note the extra `2` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, my question was really stupid !

thank you for your help @David Maze, it works now !

```
services:
  influxdb:
    image: influxdb:2.7.3
    ports:
      - '8086:8086'
      - '8088:8088'
    volumes:
      - "/data/docker-volumes/influxdb/data:/var/lib/influxdb2"
      - "/etc/ssl/myserver:/etc/ssl/myserver"
    environment:
      - INFLUXDB_DB=db0
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER=${INFLUXDB_USERNAME}
      - INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${INFLUXDB_PASSWORD}
      - INFLUXD_TLS_CERT=${TLS_CERT}
      - INFLUXD_TLS_KEY=${TLS_KEY}
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - "/data/docker-volumes/grafana/data:/var/lib/grafana"
      - "/home/docker-compose/grafana-provisioning:/etc/grafana/provisioning"
      - "/etc/ssl/myserver:/etc/ssl/myserver"
    depends_on:
      - influxdb
    environment:
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_USER=${GRAFANA_USERNAME}
      - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${GRAFANA_PASSWORD}
      - GF_SERVER_PROTOCOL=https
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_FILE=${TLS_CERT}
      - GF_SERVER_CERT_KEY=${TLS_KEY}
      - GF_SERVER_DOMAIN=url
      - GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=https://url:3000
```